# Gimp-Fu/Tinyscheme: unquoting symbols in function-defining macro

Tags: macros, scheme, gimp, script-fu

I'm attempting to write a tinyscheme macro to define four mostly-identical procedures in GIMP:

```
(macro (define-layer-moving-function body) 
       (let* (
              (func-name (cadr body))
              (direction (caddr body))
              (x-off (cadddr body))
              (y-off (cadddr (cdr body)))
              )
       `(begin 
        ;(define (func-name img layer) ;binding doesn't happen
        (define (,func-name img layer) ;variable is not a symbol
                (begin
                  (gimp-layer-translate layer ,x-off ,y-off)
                  (gimp-displays-flush))) 
        (script-fu-register
          (symbol->string ,func-name)
          (string-append "Translate layer " ,direction)                        
          (string-append "Moves current layer slightly " ,direction)                        
          "mugwhump"
          "Foobar License"
          "August 2014"
          ""                                    
          SF-IMAGE "Image" 0
          SF-DRAWABLE "Drawable" 0
        )

        (script-fu-menu-register (symbol->string ,func-name) "<Image>/Move Layer")
)))

(define-layer-moving-function 'script-fu-move-layer-down "down" 0 10)
(define-layer-moving-function 'script-fu-move-layer-up "up" 0 -10)
(define-layer-moving-function 'script-fu-move-layer-left "left" -10 0)
(define-layer-moving-function 'script-fu-move-layer-right "right" 10 0)
```

The problem is this line: `(define (,func-name img layer)`

Specifically the `,func-name` bit. When I unquote `,func-name`, I get the error "variable is not a symbol." But I'm pretty sure `,func-name` *is* a symbol, because `(symbol->string ,func-name)` works fine.

If I don't unquote `func-name`, the gimp "procedure" doesn't get bound, presumably because the function wasn't defined with the right name. The procedure gets registered and shows up in the menu, but when I try to use it I get this "unbound variable script-fu-move-layer-down" error.

Ideas? I'm guessing it's related to how `define` doesn't evaluate its first argument, but I'm lost otherwise. Here's a [Page on tinyscheme macros](http://pasture.kerosenecow.net/archive/2011/11/Script_fu_Tinyscheme_Macros.html) if you're not familiar with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A macro doesn't evaluate it's argument so `func-name` gets bound to `(quote script-fu-move-layer-down)` (or `'script-fu-move-layer-down` for short) which is indeed not a symbol but a list of two symbols.

Perhaps it will work if you call it like this?:

```
(define-layer-moving-function script-fu-move-layer-down "down" 0 10)
```

Comment: Ah yes, that works. Didn't know that about macros not evaluating their arguments, thanks.

Comment: @mugwhump You don't need macro to make the different functions. It might happen you even can `register-fo..` before it's defined and it becomes almost identical with a procedure that return a procedure.. eg. `(define script-fu-move-layer-down (make-move-layer "script-fu-move-layer-down" "down" 0 10))`